# Issues with the TouchWiz music app on my Galaxy Note 2

Tags: lock-screens, music, music-player, samsung-touchwiz, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I've recently received a Galaxy Note II, and am still in the phase of getting to know Android and Touchwiz. I've managed to sync some music onto it with iSyncr, but am having some problems playing it. I have two main issues:

Half the time when I'm in the music app on the now playing screen, clicking the back key or song list button takes me to the current artist/album I'm listening to, and clicking back from there (presumably to go to the full list of artists/albums) takes me back to the now playing screen. So I have no way to choose another song to listen to. Sometimes it does this, sometimes it doesn't. It's weird.

Second, I can't seem to find a way to get lockscreen music controls (short of installing a new lockscreen) that works. Supposedly TouchWiz puts music controls for you if you have a pattern or passcode, but that didn't seem to work. I tried as a replacement using the notification bar's music controls, but those sometimes just weren't there (I have no idea why).

And one other thing- is it possible to set a volume limit as you can on iOS? Because when I listen to music anything above half is too loud and the increments below that are too big.

These are pretty specific issues, but if anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since no one answered, I'll answer with what I eventually figured out.

1. I just installed a new music player, because I hate Samsung's.
2. I used WidgetLocker to put widgets on my lockscreen, and Phantom Music Control to get a better-looking widget to put on my lockscreen.